# Best technique to thread a web service call

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections

I have a website that needs to call a web service 1 to 10,000 times.  Currently this is done in foreach loop something like this:

```
List<Address> addresses
List<Response> responses = new List<Response>();
foreach(Address address in addresses){
  //Setup web service call
  //Call web service
  //Parse response into object for front end
  responses.Add(CustomReponseObject)
}
// The responses object is then just serialized and set to the front end client to parse through.
```

The current approach is not threaded and I'd like to speed it up.  Not sure if I should use managed threads or go with the new Async Await keywords.

I started this process and then got hung up on if the new Async keyword might work, using a lock on the responses List, or if something like a ConcurrentBag might be needed?  I've read through all three options, but not sure which option would be best for my use case?

Comment: Can you please show sample how `async` is alternative to `ConcurrentBag`? (Note that generally "best approach" questions are opinion based/too broad without concrete goal. There is nothing currently in you post that shows why you current approach is not acceptable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use async/await because it will minimize the use of managed threads while waiting for the IO operations from calling the web services to complete.

There is a [full example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh696703.aspx) showing this exact pattern.

As for the container, you would have to control access to the list while adding via a lock when each thread adds if you stick with `List<T>` as that class is not thread safe when modifying (multiple threads can read concurrently).

A better choice is `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, as it is optimized for this read/write pattern (thanks @Scott for the observation).

Comment: Did you really mean place a lock on the list object itself?  I favor a separate, private locking object.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: No, I always use a private locking object too.  I'll make that clearer in my answer.

Comment: One other point about `ConcurrentBag<T>`, it is optimized for situations where the same thread is both inserting in to and pulling out of the bag (for example a object pool where many threads are taking and returning items to the pool), this is called a "Mixed producer-consumer scenario". For a "Pure producer-consumer scenario" where a thread either adds or removes from the collection but not both a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` has better performance. See the MSDN artice "[When to Use a Thread-Safe Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997373.aspx)" for more information.

Comment: Thanks Scott, good observation that I had not considered.  I'm updating my answer based on this and another inaccuracy that I just observed.

Comment: My use case has the container being fully loaded before being traversed, so ConcurrentQueue makes sense over a ConcurrentBag, but what about a ConcurrentQueue vs a locked List?

Comment: If you carefully lock the list only when needed I suspect performance will be similar, but I would tend to use the ConcurrentQueue only because it already provides the locking semantics I need, and there is no chance that I would introduce a bug.  It supports `IEnumerable<T>` and `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, so you can read the result similar to how you would read the result for a list.  If needed, once processing is complete, you can always convert it to a list with .ToList().